# REST API return top 100 items (ordered)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, rest

I have an ajax request to retrieve the items from a list:

`/_api/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/Items?$top=100&$orderby=Created&$select=......`

Now this returns me 100 of items, but they're ordered only after they're returned.

Is it possible to order all the items in the list first and then return 100 newest items?

**For example:**

My list has 105 items.

My current request returns items with IDs 1-100 ordered by Created date.

I need my request to return the items with IDs 6-105 (100 newest items).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/Items?$top=100&$orderby=Created desc
```

It worked for me.